# how to make a subselect in cassandra db

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to recover the last state of my object, but this sub select does not work, I've seen that the new version of cassandra db supports aggregate operations and subqueries.

```
select * from event_store 
   where event_version = (select max(event_version) from event_store) 
    ALLOW FILTERING;
```

> SyntaxException: line 1:49 no viable alternative at input 'select' (...from event_store where event_version = [(]select...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by using 2 separate queries:

```
select max(event_version) from event_store;
```

and then

```
select * from event_store where event_version = 2 allow filtering;
```

I might be a bit outdated but it looks like there is no sub select support:

Work on this ticket is stopped

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8846

There were some attempts to do this:

https://github.com/jobmthomas/Cassandra-SubQuery

But overall this is just not supported in cassandra.

Comment: One potential problem is that the sub-select could be returning a very large number of event versions... (millions) It's just not something Cassandra is expected to be capable to do on the backend.